# Return partial Entity from EntityManager

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jersey, entitymanager

`JPA-QL` states that I should be able to query an Entity with `select s.message from Status s`, which does works in an `JPA-QL` console.

However, what I'd really like to do is only return specific properties of the Entity in a return list, like so:

```
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public List<Status> getIt() {
    EntityManager em = PersistenceManager.INSTANCE.getEntityManager();
    List<Status> results = em.createQuery("select s.message from Status s").getResultList();

    return results;
}
```

That errors out, though, with no real error message at all.
I can see that Hibernate ran this query:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        status0_.ID as col_0_0_ 
    from
        LIBRARY.TABLE status0_
```

A traditional `select s from Status s` works just fine:

```
@GET
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public List<Status> getIt() {
    EntityManager em = PersistenceManager.INSTANCE.getEntityManager();
    List<Status> results = em.createQuery("select s from Status s").getResultList();

    return results;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA 2.0: Load a subset of fields for an entity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6526048/jpa-2-0-load-a-subset-of-fields-for-an-entity)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want only to retrieve one primitive of an entity, `getResultList()` will return a List<> of this primitive.
In your case, if `s.message` is `String`, the result type is `List<String>`.

However, we often use more than just one element. Typically, we use **constructor expressions** for that. They are very powerful because we can map queries with joins to one data object or - as in your case - select only the fields we really want.

Assume a Transfer Object like this:

```
public class TO {
    Long id;
    String message;
    public TO(Long id, String message) {
        this.id = id;
        this.message = message;
}
```

Then you can create a query (I prefer TypedQueries):

```
TypedQuery<TO> qry = em.createQuery("SELECT NEW org.mypackage.TO(s.id, s.message) FROM Status s", TO.class);
List<TO> myList = qry.getResultList();
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: And +1 for use of a constructor expression to avoid the stream of primitives in the result set.  This is particularly useful when the subset of fields you want to fetch are of different types, like a long and a String.

Answer (score 1):

`List<Status> results = em.createQuery("select s.message from Status s").getResultList();`

You are querying for the message of status, but typing it to `List<Status>`.
I believe it should be :

`List results = em.createQuery("select s.message from Status s").getResultList();`

Because what you expect to get back from getResultList() is the untyped list.